# Convert Racket colors to and from CSS colors

Tags: css, colors, racket

What's the easiest way to turn a CSS color string like `"orange"` or `"#def"` or `"#123456"` into a Racket `color%` object, do some manipulations to the color object, and turn the result back into a CSS color string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS color string can be looked up using [color-database](https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/color-database___.html). AFAIK, there's no built-in support for converting hex color to `color%`.

If you are willing to install packages, however, you can use `string->color%` and `hex-triplet->color%` from [Pict Abbrevs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict-abbrevs/index.html) package.

Once you have a `color%` object, you can query for RGB components, so converting back to hex color should be easy. I don't know a good way to convert back to CSS color string besides creating an inverse map of the color database manually.

Note that there's also [CSS tools](https://github.com/mbutterick/css-tools), but it's unstable and doesn't use `color%`.